# Estimates and convenient decomposition of the sphere $S^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a paper in PDEs and following some estimates, although I could follow all the estimates, at some point the author uses a nice decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, this makes the estimates work but I cannot understand very well neither the decomposition nor the picture behind it, even though it seems to be very elementary. These are details:

Fix some non-zero vector $u_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the author wants to obtain estimates involving $\vert{u_{0}-v}\vert$ for $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. In order to do this the author proposes the following decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$:

$A=\lbrace v:\vert v\vert\geq 2\vert u_{0}\vert\rbrace $

$B=\lbrace v:\vert v\vert\leq 2\vert u_{0}\vert, \vert u_{0}-v\vert\leq\vert v_{}\vert/2\rbrace $

$C=\lbrace v:\vert v\vert\leq 2\vert u_{0}\vert, \vert u_{0}-v\vert\geq 2\vert v_{}\vert\rbrace $

$D=\lbrace v:\vert  v\vert\leq 2\vert u_{0}\vert, \vert v_{}\vert/2\leq\vert u_{0}-v\vert\leq 2 \vert v_{}\vert\rbrace $

Then the author works on each of these sets to obtain the desire estimates.

My question is the following: The set $A$ is just the exterior of the ball with radius $2\vert u_{0}\vert $, that is clear, however I do not have a clear idea about what it is going on inside this sphere i.e. how the sets $B,C,D$ decompose the sphere. It is clear that $B,C,D$ exhaust the sphere and the way they are defined are convenient to do the estimates, however I am wondering if there is a geometric picture behind that suggest this decomposition.

I would appreciate any insight, picture, or comment you could provide into this decomposition.

Thanks